# Apache mod_proxy site alias, alternative domains

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

Guys! Having a problem with apache mod_proxy, hoping someone can help

Preface: We need a new domain (http://section1.info) to direct users to (http://domain.info/?q=section1) and maintain section1.info in the URLs.

The following does not seem to work:

```
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass               /       http://domain.info/?q=section1
    ProxyPassReverse        /       http://domain.info/?q=section1
```

Thanks!